# How to specify native library search path for python

Tags: python

I have installed lxml which was built using a standalone version of libxml2. Reason for this was that the lxml needed a later version of libxml2 than what was currently installed.

When I use the lxml module how do I tell it (python) where to find the correct version of the libxml2 shared library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a `.so` file, it's not up to Python to find it -- it's up to the operating system's dynamic library loaded.  For Linux, for example, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the environment variable you need to set.